# JDBC/Access: user lacks privilege or object not found

Tags: java, database, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

I am trying to insert a tuple from an input relation INPUTRel into a source relation UK_RD_Spend with a foreign key, then update the tuple of the target relation UK_Status. UK_Status and UK_RD_Spend has a primary key-foreign key relation.

Here are the parameters:
INPUTRel: TransId, Company, ICB_Code, RD2008
UK_RD_Spend: Company, ICB_Code, RD_spend_2008
UK_Status: Company: RD08

So I am inserting a tuple from INPUTRel into UK_RD_Spend. It succeeded.
But when I try to update the tuple of UK_Status, it returned SQLException.

I am trying to update RD08, but I also need to check if foreign key constraint is being violated (if company name doesn't exist in UK_RD_Spend). However, I am getting errors of this:

```
SQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.3 user lacks privilege or object not found:
```

I am not sure how to fix it. The part of my code is as follow:

```
String queryFK = "SELECT * FROM UK_Status WHERE Company = "
                    + company + "";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryFK);
            pstmt.setString(1, company);
            pstmt.setDouble(2, RD2008);
            String msg1;
            try {
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

            } catch (SQLException se) {
                // Check FK Violation: company must exist
                if (t2.get(company).getCompany() == null) {
                // or this ?->
                // if
                // (!(conn.createStatement()).executeQuery(queryFK).next())
                // {
                    String ICB_CodeTest = Integer.toString(ICB_Code);
                    String RD2008Test = Double.toString(RD2008);
                    ICB_CodeTest = ICB_CodeTest.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    RD2008Test = RD2008Test.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    msg1 = "Transaction "
                            + tid
                            + " failed due to a FK constraint, for the following values of the input; ("
                            + company + ", " + ICB_Code + ", " + RD2008
                            + ")";
                    String fk2 = "INSERT INTO OUTPUTRel"
                            + "(TransId, RunMessages) " + "values (?, ?)";
                    pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(fk2);
                    pstmt.setInt(1, tid);
                    pstmt.setString(2, msg1);
                    pstmt.execute();
                    pstmt.close();
                    continue;
                }
            }
            //
            String companyName = t2.get(company).getCompany();
            Status s = t2.get(companyName);
            s.setRD2008(RD2008);

            String query = "UPDATE UK_Status SET RD08 = ? WHERE Company = ?";
            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setDouble(1, s.getRD2008());
            pstmt.setString(2, company);

            int number = (int) s.getRD2008();

            if (number < ICB_Code) {
                msg = "Transaction "
                        + tid
                        + " succeeded for the following values of the input; ("
                        + company + ", " + ICB_Code + ", " + RD2008 + ")";
                pstmt.execute();
                // Finally insert execution result on the output table.
                String oo = "INSERT INTO OUTPUTRel"
                        + "(TransId, RunMessages) " + "values (?, ?)";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(oo);
                pstmt.setInt(1, tid);
                pstmt.setString(2, msg);
                pstmt.execute();
                pstmt.close();
            } else {
                msg = "Transaction "
                        + tid
                        + " failed due to a dynamic constraint, for the following values of the input; ("
                        + company + ", " + ICB_Code + ", " + RD2008 + ")";
                // Finally insert execution result on the output table.
                String dynamicFail = "INSERT INTO OUTPUTRel"
                        + "(TransId, RunMessages) " + "values (?, ?)";
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(dynamicFail);
                pstmt.setInt(1, tid);
                pstmt.setString(2, msg);
                pstmt.execute();
                pstmt.close();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String queryFK = "SELECT * FROM UK_Status WHERE Company = "
                + company + "";
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryFK);
        pstmt.setString(1, company);
        pstmt.setDouble(2, RD2008);
        String msg1;
        try {
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

        } catch (SQLException se) {
```

Your statement can't be used as PreparedStatement because you put in the value instead of an `?`. That's where the error comes from BTW, because you haven't quoted the value, so the database looks for a column with the name of the company rather than looking for a row with the value of `company` in column `Company'.

Also you execute the statement by using `executeUpdate` which will not work with a select-statement and will not return a resultset you can iterate over.

Comment: I tried changing preparedStatement to Statement but it won't allow me to. I tried changing 'company' to '?' it won't allow me either.
What should I do to fix it? Thank you

Comment: I tried changing "+company+" to ? , now the error is Invalid argument in JDBC call: parameter index out of range: 2

Comment: @ABComputer That's coming from the `setDouble` where you attempt to set the second parameter of a statement with only one parameter.

Comment: So i simply removed the setString and setDouble, is that correct? 
For the catch part, i changed to
try { pstmt.execute();
 } catch (SQLException se) {
 if (se.getSQLState().equals("S1000")) {
....

now when I run, every transaction just give the output message of "failed due to a FK constraint violation.."

Comment: Or if I dont do "S1000" , instead i change the if statement to:

if (!(conn.createStatement()).executeQuery(queryFK).next()) , 

i will get nullPointerException for this line:
String companyName = t2.get(company).getCompany();

@Lothar

Comment: @ABComputer I don't know what `t2` is and I think I answered your original question. Further questions about different things should be asked in a new question.

Comment: t2 is a hashMap of the UK_Status relation. which is <String, Double>.

Comment: thanks for help, I cant post til 90 minutes later but I hv no time.
error is user lacks privilege or object not found: MEGGITT
Meggitt is the company of the1st tuple of the INPUTRel. It succeeds insert into, so now my UK_RD_Spend has two Meggitt with unique ICB_Code. But when I try to update the company(Meggitt) and RD08 io UK_Status, I get the error. If I remove the if conditionfort fk constraint, it shows` nullpointerexception` for my `t2.get(company).getCompany();`
getCompany is a method to return this.company; in RD08 class. RD08 class is the map value of t1 (UK_RD_Spend)